# Split tables with a specific height

Tags: jquery, html-table

**How do I split a table:**

I have a table that i want to split in different tables when the rows are to long. I made a script that measures the height of row and adds it up to the height till a specific height is met. Then the class "new-row" will be added. That is as far as I come...

**Javascript jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var init_height = $("table").height();   // total table height
  var max_height = 400;                    // example max height
  if(init_height > max_height) {
    var pages = Math.ceil(init_height / max_height);
  }
  var start_height = 0;                    // start counter
  $("table").find("tr").each(function(){
    start_height = start_height + $(this).height();
    if(start_height > max_height) {
      $(this).addClass("new");             // marks the new table
      start_height = 0;                    // reset counter
    }
  });

  //$(this).find('.new'); ???????????

});
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Dolor sit amet..... etc</td>
    <tr>
    <!-- a lot more rows here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCK89/) you can see the rows that should begin in a new table marked red. My desired outcome would also have the theads in every new table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/BCK89/1/

```
$(".new").each(function () {
  $("<table>").insertAfter("table:last");
  $("<thead>").append("table:last");
  $(this).nextUntil('.new').addBack().appendTo("table:last");
});
```

I'm not sure whether you want to leave the `.new` in the old table or not.  If you don't, remove `.addBack`.  You will also have to fill the `<thead>`, but that should be pretty easy.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `.addBack` is new to jQuery 1.9, and is equivalent to `.andSelf` in older versions.

Comment: @Blazemonger I think you're wrong about that: http://jsfiddle.net/8Qae5/ -- it's just that `.andSelf` is deprecated now, I think

Comment: You are correct -- [apparently it was added quietly in 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).

Comment: thanks to your answer i fixed it now, btw i made a mistake with the reset counter, because .new is the beginning of a new table it's height should also be added to counter after its reset.. sorry not my native explaining language. result: http://jsfiddle.net/BCK89/2/